# Groovy: Perfect forwarding

Tags: groovy, perfect-forwarding

I want to make a closure, say `print_args`, that takes another closure, say `f`, that prints it's arguments than passes the arguments to `f`.

My first attempt at this was the following:

```
def print_args(f) { { Object... args -> args.each { println it }; f(*args) } }
```

So, if we also define:

```
def add = { x, y -> x + y }
```

We can then do:

```
println add(1,2)

def print_args_add = print_args(add)

println print_args_add(1,2)
```

And as can be seen, `print_args_add` is just a closure which does `add` but also prints it's arguments.

We can also define `sum`:

```
def sum = { x -> x.inject { acc, val -> acc + val } }
```

And similarly:

```
println sum([1,2])

def print_args_sum = print_args(sum)
println print_args_sum([1,2])
```

This works fine for passing `arrayList`s. However, when passing ordinary arrays:

```
Object x = new Object[2]
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2

println sum(x)
```

Works fine, but the following:

```
println print_args_sum(x)
```

breaks, as the closure `print_args` expands the passed array instead of passing it as is.

Is there a way I can write `print_args` so it can deal with closures `f` that can be passed a single array as an argument, without putting addition constraints on the caller or what closures `print_args` can deal with?

I've placed the code on ideone [here](http://ideone.com/940xpi).

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911788/groovy-detecting-when-being-passed-arrays

Comment: Did you achieve what you were looking for from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Treat an object array as `List`, if it is passed.

The reason you have to do like that is because of `sum` closure which takes only one parameter. Spread operator on an object array would yield to two parameters in the case where it errors out. So you would need to below enhancement in `print_args`

```
def print_args(f) { 
    {Object... args -> 
        args.each { println it}
        args.find{it instanceof List} ? f(*args) : f(args as List)
    }
}
```